Can you model relativistic interactions without locality?
Assume $c=1$
I've been doing relativity by myself so I may be making some assumptions here that I would not have if my learning had been more extensive.
One such assumption is that you can model the interaction of say two objects using the position and time coordinates of an inertial perspective.
Say we're trying to do such a task, here are two arbitrary worldlines from my perspective in red and my current time in green.

Lets say that the two objects are interacting by some force proportional to their separation, but currently the bottom worldline's $x$ coordinate dips in to my future, attempting to observe points that have not yet been created.

Here's the interval from $x=0$ to $0.25$ for the bottom worldline at the current time in purple.
Now the problem is that I can't predict the force applied to the bottom worldline when I do not yet know where the top worldline will be according to it.
I believe this issue is resolved when you force interactions to obey locality, since it restricts the domain of influence to my past or present, never the future.
So the question is, is there some way of resolving this issue without resorting to locality?
Given this issue, is my assumption that the physics of these objects can be modeled using an observers coordinates wrong?
Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

When trying to model stuff in SR, you need to already know the form of the interaction. And it is the view of each particle that the other particle is seeing, nothing to do with the observer's. In fact, if you looked up Feynman lectures, he mentioned an extremely important consideration that was omitted by earlier authors, that resulted in wrong conclusions: Namely, that the force appears to not come from the time-retarded position, but rather the time-retarded position extrapolated into the present-time by the time-retarded velocity. i.e. the details are not at all trivial.

So are you saying that an observer cannot simulate the path of another particle only using its own coordinates?

No, an observer can simulate just fine. You just needed to have the correct data and the correct equations of motion.

Ok, but would those equations, if the force depended on distance, be based on the time-retarded position (with the velocity consideration) rather than the instantaneous position at my current time?
Also since you really only mentioned locality, was I right in thinking that non-local formulations don't work?

Bear in mind that Newtonian gravity requires that the force of gravity is instantaneous and that a finite speed of gravity and a retarded position would cause instabilities. GR does not depend on gravitational force at all, so the concept of gravitational interaction speed does not apply. The orbiting object simply follows a geodesic in the pre-existing curved spacetime around a gravitational "source".
